# "This PC" document and picture selections won't target folders in the user's folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive, documents, pictures

Windows 10. After some messing around, OneDrive has been uninstalled, and all my personal folders are in my user's-name folder on the C drive as they should be. My libraries have been defined to direct me correctly to the files in these folders. However, the document and picture icons shown in File Explorer under "This PC" want to direct me to the OneDrive folder in my user's-name folder. I've been unable to correct this misdirection, so I've created documents and pictures folders in the OneDrive folder and put within them shortcuts to the documents and pictures folders in my user's-name folder. That's the best I've been able to do about the "This PC" interface.

I'd like to have the documents and pictures icons under "This PC" direct me properly but have been unable to find any way to do it. The properties window for the documents folder, unlike that window for the other folders, does not have the "location" tab.

Comment: please edit add some screenshots ; it helps to understand the problem better

Comment: I suggest you create a new **adminisrator account**, then login into the new account, go to `C:\Users`, copy files from previous account to a new account.

Comment: You should have turned off OneDrive's "backup" of your folders, which actually relocates them under the OneDrive folder, as those are the only folders that sync to OneDrive. Deselecting Desktop, Documents, and Pictures restores those folders to their default locations.